# Can't import module using package.json "exports" in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, node-modules

I am trying to import a (typescript) package into a (typescript) React project. This modules uses the `exports` property in the `package.json` file to control what can be imported from it. But, in my React project, I can not get the paths exported in `exports` to work. Instead, I can import anything from the module. So for example, I export a path `./certificate` using `exports` in `package.json`. But instead of importing like:

```js
import {test} from "certificationtypes/certificate"
```

I need to import like:

```js
import {test} from "certificationtypes/src/certificate"
```

(It also exposes all other files not exported using the `exports` directive).

This is the `package.json` of the module:

```json
{
  "name": "inputsvalidator",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./build/src/index.js",
  "exports": {
    "./certificate": "./build/src/certificate.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "prepare": "npm run build",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/validator": "^13.7.10",
    "certificationtypes": "file:../certificationTypes",
    "countries": "file:../../../../../lib/shared/countries",
    "types": "file:../../../../../lib/shared/types",
    "validator": "^13.7.0"
  }
}
```

The strange thing is that this does work in Node.js projects! So is there something extra I should do to also make this work in my React project? I did read that this should be supported using webpack.

My `package.json` for my React project:

```json
{
  "name": "front-end",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.11",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.26",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "certificationtypes": "file:../../lib/shared/certificationTypes",
    "countries": "file:../../../../lib/shared/countries",
    "inputsvalidator": "file:../../lib/shared/inputsValidator",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-spinners": "^0.13.7",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.6",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4",
    "validator": "^13.7.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.26"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3003"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, TypeScript does not regard `"exports"` fields in package.json files when importing packages.

In TypeScript 4.7 or later, this feature can be enabled explicitly in the compiler options by setting [`moduleResolution`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#moduleResolution) to `"node16"` or `"nodeNext"` in the current project (there is nothing the import*ed* package can do to enforce this setting), e.g.

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "moduleResolution": "node16",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Just be careful that doing so may unexpectedly break other parts of your applications, because then other settings in package.json start to play a role as well.